# strange linux zip command behaviour

Tags: linux, centos, compression

I run this on my CentOs box:

```
zip -r backup.zip /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/
```

The command works ok as it should, but I have an annoying problem.

What I expect is when I open the zip to have one folder in it: `public_html`

Instead i have `/home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/`. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like expected behavior, not strange behavior.

To get what you want, try this:

```
cd /home/user/domains/example.com
zip -r /srv/backups/example.com/backup.zip public_html
```

Comment: I run the above though a php script. Will what you suggest works with php exec ?

Comment: Change directories with PHP's [`chdir()`](http://www.php.net/chdir) call instead of the `cd` command, then. Otherwise it's the same.